# Heatmap Renderer ArcGIS Javascript 4.4 based on number of points and their locality to each other in the layer only

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have been reviewing the documentation for the heatmap renderer but I would like to tag it to my feature layer without visualising based on the "field" but based on the number of points and their locality between each other. Could anyone advise me how to?

```
var earthquakeLayer = new FeatureLayer({
  // url to a point dataset
});

// visualization based on field

var heatmapParams = {
  layer: earthquakeLayer,
  view: view,
  field: "magnitude"
};

// when the promise resolves, apply the renderer to the layer
heatmapRendererCreator.createRenderer(heatmapParams)
  .then(function(response){
    earthquakeLayer.renderer = response.renderer;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are actually looking for clustering features ([ArcGIS API Doc - FeatureReductionCluster](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-FeatureReductionCluster.html)). There are several examples there, take a look if it fits your needs.